# Loading 1st Scene Randomly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am familiar with loading a random scene. For example using Random.Range:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

int index = Random.Range(1,4);
SceneManager.LoadLevel(index);
```

However, what I would like to do is make the very first scene that loads be random. Is there a simple way of doing this that I am missing?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if there is built in method but this is what i would do:

- Create empty scene
- Add script to it with random scene generator
- Load new random scene

I think this is the simplest solution if there is no built in method.

Comment: Hi Aleksa, I'll try that. Sounds like the simple solution that was evading me. I'll post later if it works. Cheers! J.